# UISwitch not displaying on/off in other languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiswitch

I am using a UISwitch in the ViewController, it displays as ON and OFF, but when I change to different language like french and spanish , the UISwitch is displayin as 1/0 . What is the reason ? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758053/iphone-uiswitch-text-in-non-english-language-is-i-o-instead-of-on-off-in-some-l). You no need to worry. Its common in iOS all over the world.

Comment: Oh ok. Can I add any custom text for the Switch ? OR Can I make the ON/OFF common for all the languages ?

Comment: Find the tutorial in the below link.

Comment: http://www.catamount.com/blog/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this custom switch,

https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch